# Colored Icons In NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-navigationview

Good day, **Is there a way, displaying colored icons on navigation drawer?
Not tinting them or setting them to black, and each of them will have corresponding color (highlight/background) when click, in navigation drawer.**

Just like Google Store App drawer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes you can add colored icon using menu group items:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_artist"
        android:icon="@drawable/artist"
        android:title="Artists"/>
```

And for highlighting the selcted item Use the code below for default selection:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

And You can select(highlight) the item by calling

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
```

**Edit**

If you are using navigationview you can edit option for changing the colortint of icons as follows:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_all"

    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:theme="@style/list_item_appearance"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >
```

**Edit**

If you set `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` you will get colored icons.

Comment: I tried that one. I added colored icons, but still it appears to be gray. Not the colored one. I'm using switch for intents. When the icons is click.

Comment: Is this applicable also to vector images? Their original color? Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: @RoCk thanks for accepting the answer, you can also upvote if it is useful. well i didn't try vector images yet. I will explore and tell you then.

Comment: @RoCk check for edit and please upvote if you find it useful :)

Comment: what is the kotlin equvalent

Comment: Edit save my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can set it in your Activity.Class

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your menu xml by making checked equal to true in your code for example

```xml
<item
    android:id="@+id/home_action"
    android:checked="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title="@string/home" />
```