# Navigation drawer set menu item icon color

Tags: android

How can I change just one of menu item icon color in Android's navigation drawer? I don't want to change the entire drawers icon but just one icon.

I tried setting the `android:iconTint` property but that does not work.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Well just put the Icon of your desired color in the resource folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915607/change-specific-icons-color-in-navigationdrawer

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35455531/8476022